# I am not sure how to detect a click in roblox on a tool

Tags: lua, roblox

this is the code I have used

```
local tool = Instance.new("Tool")
tool.RequiresHandle = false
tool.Parent = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Backpack

function onActivation()
    print("Tool activated")
end

tool.Activated:Connect(onActivation)
```

I'm not exactly sure how this works but it keeps giving the error "attempt to index nil with 'Backpack'" and I am new to coding so it would be great if someone can help me out with this I am trying to make it detect a click so I can give a leaderstat.

Comment: That means `game.Players.LocalPlayer` is nil. What do you expect it to be?

Answer (score 1):

You probably put this into a Script. It needs to be in a "LocalScript" and run on the client. For example, put the LocalScript into "StarterPlayerScripts".

Also you should do

```
tool.Parent = game.Players.LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("Backpack")
```

since the BackPack object might not be loaded when the code is executed.

Comment: So I've added that but how would I implement that into the script I have, for example, I want to give the player a stat called fist whenever the player clicks on the tool called fist which should be in the backpack